# rpy2 does not convert back to pandas

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe, rpy2

I have an R object that will not convert to Pandas, and the strange part is that it doesn't throw an error.

**Updated with the code I'm using, sorry not to supply that up front -- and to miss the request for 2 weeks!**

Python code that calls an R script

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import datetime
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter


def serial_date_to_string(srl_no):
    new_date = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0) + datetime.timedelta(srl_no - 1)
    return new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

jurisdiction='TX'
r=ro.r
r_df=r['source']('farrington.R')

with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    pd_from_r_df = ro.conversion.rpy2py(r_df)
```

The issue is that pd_from_r_df returns an R object rather than a Pandas dataframe:

```
>>> pd_from_r_df
R object with classes: ('list',) mapped to:
[ListSexpVector, BoolSexpVector]
  value: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector object at 0x7faa4c4eff08> [RTYPES.VECSXP]
  visible: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.BoolSexpVector'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.BoolSexpVector object at 0x7faa4c4e7948> [RTYPES.LGLSXP]
```

Here's the R script "farrington.R", which returns a surveillance time series, which ro.conversion.rpy2py isn't (as used above) converting to a pandas dataframe

```
library('surveillance')
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
w<-1
b<-3
nfreq<-52
steps_back<- 28
alpha<-0.05

counts <- read_csv("Weekly_counts_of_death_by_jurisdiction_and_cause_of_death.csv")
counts<-counts[,!colnames(counts) %in% c('Cause Subgroup','Time Period','Suppress','Note','Average Number of Deaths in Time Period','Difference from 2015-2019 to 2020','Percent Difference from 2015-2019 to 2020')]
wide_counts_by_cause<-pivot_wider(counts,names_from='Cause Group',values_from='Number of Deaths',values_fn=(`Cause Group`=sum))
wide_state <- filter(wide_counts_by_cause,`State Abbreviation`==jurisdiction)
wide_state <- filter(wide_state,Type=='Unweighted')
wide_state[is.na(wide_state)] <-0
important_columns=c('Alzheimer disease and dementia','Cerebrovascular diseases','Heart failure','Hypertensive dieases','Ischemic heart disease','Other diseases of the circulatory system','Malignant neoplasms','Diabetes','Renal failure','Sepsis','Chronic lower respiratory disease','Influenza and pneumonia','Other diseases of the respiratory system','Residual (all other natural causes)')

all_columns <- append(c('Year','Week'),important_columns)

selected_wide_state<-wide_state[, names(wide_state) %in% all_columns]
start<-c(as.numeric(min(selected_wide_state[,'Year'])),as.numeric(min(selected_wide_state[,'Week'])))
freq<-as.numeric(max(selected_wide_state[,'Week']))

sts <- new("sts",epoch=1:nrow(numeric_wide_state),start=start,freq=freq,observed=numeric_wide_state)
sts_4 <- aggregate(sts[,important_columns],nfreq=nfreq)
start_idx=end_idx-steps_back

cntrlFar <- list(range=start_idx:end_idx,w==w,b==b,alpha==alpha)
surveil_ts_4_far <- farrington(sts_4,control=cntrlFar)
far_df<-tidy.sts(surveil_ts_4_far)
far_df
```

(using the NCHS data here [from a couple months back] https://data.cdc.gov/NCHS/Weekly-counts-of-death-by-jurisdiction-and-cause-o/u6jv-9ijr/ )

Comment: A minimal complete code example to reproduce an issue or support a question will help see what you are exactly doing, and provide help. In the meantime, conversion is generally working. Did you check the relevant tutorial in the doc: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/pandas.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, when calling [`source()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/source) by default on a script without named functions, the returned object is a list of two named components, `$value` and `$visible`, where:

- `$value` is the last displayed or defined object which in your case is the `far_df` data frame (which in R `data.frame` is a class object extending `list` type);
- `$visible` is a boolean vector indicating if last object was displayed or not which in your case is `TRUE`. This would be `FALSE` had you ended script at `far_df <- tidy.sts(surveil_ts_4_far)`.

In fact, your Python error confirms this output indicatating a list of `[ListSexpVector, BoolSexpVector]`.

Therefore, since you only want the first item, index for first item accordingly by number or name.

```
r_raw = ro.r['source']('farrington.R')        # IN R: r_raw <- source('farrington.R')
r_df  = r_raw[0]                              # IN R: r_df  <- r_raw[1]
r_df  = r_raw[r_raw.names.index('value')]     # IN R: r_df  <- r_raw$value

with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    pd_from_r_df = ro.conversion.rpy2py(r_df)
```